# Where is saved the value of the 'help text' of field of content type?

Tags: entities, database, tooltips

I know that you can set help text for any field in the content type, but where this text is saved in databese, because I want to access it in other way not only for tooltip?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the field instance settings (stored in the `field_config_instance` table). The preferred API method to use is [`field_info_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7):

```
$info = field_info_instance('node', 'field_foo', 'article');
$help_text = $info['description'];
```